# How to get the Next 15 days date depending on current day date?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Currently i am able to get current date of the iPhone by using following code

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString* currentDateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"User's current Date:%@",currentDateStr);
```

but i want get Next 15 days date from current date, how i can get get that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents* components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
components.day = 15;
NSDate* newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents: components toDate: self.date options: 0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setDay:+15];
NSDate *afterfifteenDays = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:todayDate options:0];
NSLog(@"todayDate: %@", todayDate);
NSLog(@"afterfifteenDays: %@", afterfifteenDays);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
NSTimeInterval totalOffset = /*time to add - in seconds */
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *endWithTZ = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:totalOffset];
```

Comment: Note that many regions on the world have a "daylight savings time", and therefore the time of a day in seconds is not constant.

Answer (score -2):

There may be a better way (and I'm watching this question to see if there is), but this is what I currently use:

```
+ (NSDate *)offsetFromDate:(NSDate *)fromDate withDays:(int)days 
{
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = (days * 86400);
    NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:timeInterval sinceDate:fromDate];    
    return date;
}
```

If you google for the number of seconds in a day, you will get the value 86400.

Comment: This is a very naive solution working in most situations but failing terribly in some other situations.

Comment: Note that many regions on the world have a "daylight savings time", and therefore some days have one hour more or less.

Comment: Indeed. The date components method is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: And you're right. I voted for duDE's answer and changing mine to use that. It's always awesome to learn new things here. =)

Answer (score -2):

```
  NSLog(@"%@", [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:15*24*60*60]);
```

Comment: this is the most simple solution

Comment: Note that many regions on the world have a "daylight savings time", and therefore some days have one hour more or less.

Comment: It fails for example on day light saving when an hour can be added or removed.

Comment: 1 hour is negligible infront of 15 days. it doesn't matter that much. Its Just fastest way to accomplish a task.

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala One hour can be a difference between two days, especially when the original date has time component close enough to midnight. This is not the correct solution and the question of simplicity is arguable.